# heightForRowAtIndexPath: was executed before cell is show?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

For example, there are 100 rows in tableView, `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` was executed already before the 100th row was show.

Why? In order to calculate `contentSize` of tableView?

Thanks!

Comment: question not clear.. maybe some relevant code would help.

Comment: yes, it will be invoked **before** the cell shows. you have to provide the cell's height to the `UITableView` and it can use it to adjust size of the `UITableViewCell`. it called for the visible cells only. no matter how huge is your database, if there is only i.e. 5 cells on the screen, it will called 5 times only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) :

> Every time a table view is displayed, it calls tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: on the delegate for each of its rows

So yes, it's called prior to displaying the cell. If you think about it, if the table did it the other way around, it would create a cell with a standard height, put the content in it, get the real height, and resize/shift the cells. That would not be really nice.

This may cause performance issues, so you should only use it if you have cells of different heights :

> The method allows the delegate to specify rows with varying heights. If this method is implemented, the value it returns overrides the value specified for the rowHeight property of UITableView for the given row.
>
> There are performance implications to using `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` instead of the rowHeight property. **Every time a table view is displayed, it calls `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` on the delegate for each of its rows**, which can result in a significant performance problem with table views having a large number of rows (approximately 1000 or more).

Otherwise, if all your cells are the same height, use the `rowHeight` property, and do not implement `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.